# Deserialization repeatedly with C# getter property

Tags: c#, json, getter-setter

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var sourceJson2 = "{\"bizType\":\"123\",\"data\":\"JzLw2uiQT4IzERg7hdGWFaPAilWJy7e4462Gd9VQ0Mbj0qZI3uDe6wWaSklECHjalCTEt/L1ZAyhf/fxocABc8PSlKIgD3WMGXM06mlnEe7XqG3MCbAyHVYJtdDKKbo9oWNnoRRzd/WOi7aiOq80AyDEYTH5in5Zc4FJO5M0JI8Dj96cG4QmRKdwG6nfBt9PrroR0mqCNacstP9GnTAZ6BpMPAAkfbmrGeLsE/kCYcBXK0EtNLSqBChKwwOUaETeWdmtCl9RDMWAvTCiOgKeWw==\",\"appKey\":\"1234567890123456\",\"Sign\":\"JzLw2uiQT4IzERg7hdGWFaPAilWJy7e4462Gd9VQ0Mbj0qZI3uDe6wWaSklECHjalCTEt/L1ZAyhf/fxocABc8PSlKIgD3WMGXM06mlnEe7XqG3MCbAyHVYJtdDKKbo9oWNnoRRzd/WOi7aiOq80AyDEYTH5in5Zc4FJO5M0JI8Dj96cG4QmRKdwG6nfBt9PrroR0mqCNacstP9GnTAZ6BpMPAAkfbmrGeLsE/kCYcBXK0EtNLSqBChKwwOUaETeWdmtCl9RDMWAvTCiOgKeWw==\",\"Amount\":null}";
        var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaidInfo>(sourceJson2);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonModel.TradeNo);//deserialization again
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class PaidInfo
{
    public string BizType { get; set; }

    private PaidData _payData;

    public PaidData PayData
    {
        get
        {
            if (_payData != null)
            {
                return this._payData;
            }
            else
            {
                var sourceJson = Aes.Decrypt(Data, AppKey);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayData>(sourceJson);
            }
        }
        set { this._payData = value; }
    }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string AppKey { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo
    {
        get => this.PayData.RequestNo;
        set => this.PayData.RequestNo = value;
    }

    public string TradeNo
    {
        get { return this.PayData.ServerRequestNo; }
        set { this.PayData.ServerRequestNo = value; }
    }

}

public class PaidData 
{
    public string RequestNo { get; set; }
    public string ServerRequestNo { get; set; }
    public string MerchantNo { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Fee { get; set; }
    public string BizCode { get; set; }
    public string BizMsg { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I access the line

```
Console.WriteLine(jsonModel.TradeNo);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(jsonModel.OrderNo);
```

which both deserialize again, the performance is affected. Why the variable `jsonModel` doesn't preserve the values after the  first deserialization?

Comment: Have you considered assigning to `this._payData` in the `else`?

Comment: Because you haven't instructed the code to store the deserialized result in `_payData`?

Comment: @XIAN Why do you expect _payData to have a value before you assign one to it?

Comment: Side note: if the names of your class properties are the same as those in the JSON you're deserializing (or serializing to), you don't need to use the JsonProperty attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign `this._payData` in your getter.

```
public PayData PayData
{
    get
    {
        if (_payData == null)
        {
            var sourceJson = Aes.Decrypt(Data, AppKey);
            this._payData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayData> (sourceJson);//<---store it
        }
        return this._payData;
    }
    set { this._payData = value; }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you mean getter?